# Select where Datediff won't work

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables. `VIP` and `transactions`

[image]

I want to get the sum of values where they are not expired date.
**expired date formula is** : `DATEADD(DAY,VIP.vipValue,[transaction].tDate)`.
and where clause must something like this:

```
DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(),DATEADD(DAY,VIP.vipValue,[transaction].tDate)) > 0
```

I try this :

```
SELECT SUM(v.vipValue) 
FROM [transaction] AS t LEFT JOIN
VIP AS v ON  v.vipId = t.vipId
WHERE  DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(),DATEADD(DAY,v.vipValue,t.tDate)) > 0
```

but it's return me null and empty result; however if I put some number instaed of `v.vipValue` (e.g: 30) I get true result. why `v.vipValue` has problem and where did I wrong?

**Update post**
[image]
to clarify, these are VIP and Transactions data
[image]
[image]

Comment: It seems the data related issue, Maybe v.vipValue contains the NULL values. It would be appreciated if you can provide the sample data

Comment: no I checked both tables and all of data has not null values

Comment: Maybe the result of the `datediff` is `<0`?

Comment: Maybe due to left join, you may have records in VIP table but do not have a matching record in the transaction table.

Comment: to clear my question: datediff must be > 0 because I need records where still doesn't expired. when I put some digit like 30 instead of v.vipValue, the query will work. i am sure there must be somthing wrong with v.vipValue

Comment: Can you provide an [mcve]? If you only select the `DATEADD` part without `where` clause, do yo get expected results (please provide those results too)?

Comment: Can you please provide the expected output for above sample data?

Comment: For the sample data given, `DATEDIFF` will result in negative values (-4 for 2018 date, -369 for 2017 date). (Assuming date is displayed in format yyyy-MM-dd).

Comment: As per the sample data provided, To get the result, you must need the date greater than "2018-01-6" for the vipValue 5.

Comment: can you write your answer?

Comment: That is not the proper way to ask an SQL question. The proper way is to provide sample data as DDL+DML (Create table and insert into statements) and expected results as formatted text. That way, we can copy the sample data to an SQL editor and test our answers before posting them.

Comment: Btw, instead of using both `DateAdd` and `DateDiff`, you can simply ask if `DateDiff` between `GetDate()` and `t.Date` is smaller than `v.vipValue`

Comment: We cannot give you an answer, because we don't know what you want. The query and data you posted match your output. Your expectation seems off.

Comment: @Zohar Peled please write your solution

Comment: Uhm, isn't it just because v.vipValue is used in the datediff while it should be v.timeout instead?

Comment: yes you are right. thanks a lot you save my day. please write your answer

Comment: I will be happy to write an answer as soon as you will [edit] your question to include the relevant tables DDL  + sample data as DML.

Comment: it's my bad. as @LukStorms says I must use v.timeout instead of v.vipValue.

Comment: yes exactly, I didn't notice that, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments, v.[timeout] should be used to compare with the date difference instead of v.vipValue.

Example code that uses table variables :

```
declare @transaction table (tId int identity(1,1), vipId int, tDate date);

declare @VIP table (vipId int, vipValue int, [timeout] int);

insert into @VIP (vipId, vipValue, [timeout]) values (1,1,1), (2,2,20), (3,3,30);
insert into @transaction (vipId, tDate) values (1,getDate()-1), (2,getDate()-1), (3,getDate()-1), (4,getDate()-1);

SELECT t.*, v.vipValue, v.[timeout], DATEDIFF(DAY,t.tDate,GETDATE()) as DayDiff
FROM @transaction AS t
LEFT JOIN @VIP AS v ON  v.vipId = t.vipId;

SELECT SUM(v.vipValue) 
FROM @transaction AS t
JOIN @VIP AS v ON v.vipId = t.vipId
WHERE v.[timeout] > DATEDIFF(DAY,t.tDate,GETDATE());
```

The second query will return 5